# Using MySQL keywords in a query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a MySQL query with keywords in it. Is there any way to encapsulate these keywords so that I can use them anyway?

Here's the query that won't execute:

```
INSERT INTO PendingPasswordRecovery (key, userID, TimeModified, TimeCreated, TimeDeleted, IsDeleted) VALUES ('test123', 1, '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '1000-01-01 00:00:00', false)
```

As you have probably guessed already, "key" is the keyword that I am using in the query, and it is unfortunately also the name of the column I want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
INSERT INTO PendingPasswordRecovery (`key`, `userID`, `TimeModified`, `TimeCreated`, `TimeDeleted`, `IsDeleted`) VALUES ('test123', 1, '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '1000-01-01 00:00:00', false)
```

I have added backticks to all column names but you could just do it for the keyword. The backticks are called "*identifier quote characters*". For more information, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 2):

Just enclose them in backquotes

```
INSERT INTO PendingPasswordRecovery (`key`, userID, TimeModified, TimeCreated, TimeDeleted, IsDeleted) VALUES ('test123', 1, '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '1000-01-01 00:00:00', false)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

[Here's the list of MySQL reserved keywords.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 1):

use ` to escape column names:

```
INSERT INTO PendingPasswordRecovery (`key`, `userID`, `TimeModified`, `TimeCreated`, `TimeDeleted`, `IsDeleted`) VALUES ('test123', 1, '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '2011-07-26 16:26:56', '1000-01-01 00:00:00', false)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to do so.
Try `key` but the better way is always to rename your field