# SELECT * FROM table throws error in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to make a select from a table, which works fine with every other table in my database, but when I try the following I recieve an error:

```
db.makeQuery("SELECT * FROM References");
```

Which calls:

```
public ResultSet makeQuery(String query) throws Exception
{
    preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
    return resultSet;

}
```

It then throws the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'References' at line 1
```

I seems very strange to me, since this statement works:

```
db.makeQuery("select * from Products");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`References` is a keyword in SQL, so you better avoid it for table names. (See for instance [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).)

As suggested by Nishant, you *can* use reserved words in queries if you escape them with backticks.

Related question:

- [Using MySQL keywords in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831674/using-mysql-keywords-in-a-query)

Comment: Yeah, changing the name of the table did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

use

```
 db.makeQuery("SELECT * FROM `References`");
```

if you can, better, avoid having names that are MySQL keywords. As suggested by [aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344054/298455)

Answer (score 0):

You might be misspelling the name of your table. MySQL gives this error when it can't find that table you're referring to.

Use `SHOW TABLES;` to see the names of the tables in your database, and double-check the name.